# Connect on SignalR Hub return 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm confused with SignalR connection, the solution working well on my computer but when hosted on the Linux server it returns some errors, SLL installed on the server.

Please anyone can guide me what is missing :(

I'm using .Net core 3.1

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 2;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddScoped<ILoginService, LoginService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAdminService, AdminService>();
            services.AddScoped<ITradingService, TradingService>();
            services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddSingleton(s =>
            {
                using var scope = s.CreateScope();
                var user = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                var config = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                var hub = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MessagesHub>>();

                return new RedisClient(hub, config, user);

            });
            services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
        }
```

..
..

```
[System.Obsolete]
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnAppStarted);

            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnAppStopping);

            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnAppStopped);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseLoggedUserMiddleware();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapHub<MessagesHub>("/messagesHub");
            });
        }
```

..
..

```
 public class MessagesHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly Logger _logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        public MessagesHub(RedisClient redisClient)
        {
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var username = Context.GetHttpContext().User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (username != null) {
                _logger.Info($"{username?.Value} connected to SignalR");
            }
            
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            var username = Context.GetHttpContext().User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (username != null)
            {
                _logger.Info($"{username?.Value} disconnected from SignalR");
            }
            if(exception != null)
            {
                _logger.Error(exception);
            }
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

and this is the code that connects on messageHub from js

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/messagesHub").build();
connection.on("ReceiveReflectionMessage", function (message) {
    newReflection = JSON.parse(message);
    handleReflection(newReflection);
});
```

And this for Layout view:

```
    <script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/js/messages.js" defer></script>
```

At the end, no messages received on the frontend due to failed connection, so what is the missing or must add some configurations ??

Comment: you answered your question. it works on local and goes on server breaks, its because of https try to bypass it somehow.

Comment: @Valkyrie So man, what to do??

Comment: I suggest you could try to check your web server has installed websocket or not. If you don't install it, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket#:~:text=On%20the%20Server%20Roles%20page,Click%20Next.&text=On%20the%20Select%20Features%20page,installation%20selections%20page%2C%20click%20Install.) to install it.

Comment: I will check and update you @BrandoZhang